# Black screen and blinking underscore post BIOS to UEFI change

Tags: bios, uefi, windows-11

I encountered an issue with my Win 11 pc yesterday. I did a conversion from Legacy BIOS to UEFI but was unsuccessful.
My reckless approach made me skip an important step which led to my pc not booting, but ending up with a black screen and a
blinking underscore after power's turned on.

My pc was missing a TPM feature, so in order for this feature to exist in my pc, the UEFI option must be enabled. My pc was missing
the UEFI option as well. This was the reason I tried to convert from BIOS to UEFI. I wasn't able to enable the UEFI feature at the end nor
had done a thorough research before pursuing this task. I didn't take any screenshots of the results, so this is all I can relate to you guys.

What I want to know is, are my pc's data lost now or are they recoverable? If recoverable or retrievable, what are my options?
Is it possible to revert to BIOS again?

Comment: `the UEFI option must be enabled` you either have UEFI or not, I take it this is a very old PC if it doesn't have UEFI ... or are you talking about disabling legacy (CSM) boot?

Comment: "I did a conversion from Legacy BIOS to UEFI" - What do you mean by this exactly?  Do you mean you disabled CSM? You can't actually convert a device's firmware from BIOS to UEFI.